# inherit width of image (css )

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a screen that 80% of it is filled with an image and the bottom 20% is a div. The image style is set so it will scale it's width proportionally to it's height. The height should fill the 80% div. 
My problem is that I want the bottom 20% div to inherit the automatically scaled width of the image.
Here is my css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #background {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
position: relative; 
overflow:hidden;
left: 0px; 
top: 0px; 
z-index: -1; /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */
}

.stretch {
max-width:100%;
height:80%;   
}
</style>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="background" >
  <img id="status_bg" src="online_pend_off.jpg" class="stretch">
</div>
<div id="twenty_per" style="background-color:blue">
</div>
```

Any idea how can I make the second div (twenty_per) have the same width as status_bg image?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the HTML inside another div with no default width (to follow `#background`s width), and `#twenty_per` should have 100% width. This way, `#twenty_per` will automatically have the same width as `#background`.

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

#twenty_per {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="background" >
        <img id="status_bg" src="online_pend_off.jpg" class="stretch">
    </div>
    <div id="twenty_per" style="background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - this is almost perfect except that the "twenty_per" div has the height of 0px. How can I make twenty_per div fill the 20% left of the screen height?

Comment: Do you mean that your first div takes up 80% and you want the `twenty_per` to take 20%? Your question is rather confusing... Could you perhaps create a fiddle to demonstrate exactly what you mean?